Cannot insert external objects to this list (IList) ERROR
I am trying to use Drag and Drop Feature from here
The program is running right but when I drag and drop a row inside the DataGrid, it shows an error saying:
'Cannot insert external objects to this list'
Below is the snippet of code where the error is generating:
private static void ExchangeItems(object sender, object targetItem)
{
    var draggeditem = VisualHelper.GetDraggedItem(sender as DependencyObject);
    if (draggeditem == null) return;
    if (targetItem != null && !ReferenceEquals(draggeditem, targetItem))
    {
        var list = (sender as DataGrid).ItemsSource as IList;
        
        //get target index
        var targetIndex = list.IndexOf((object)targetItem);
        //remove the source from the list
        list.Remove((object)draggeditem);
        
        //move source at the target's location
        list.Insert(targetIndex, draggeditem);
    }
}


You are trying to add the item container to the data item collection. Are you trying to drag row to rearrange them? And is this only at control/presentation level or do you need to reorder the source collection too?

Yes.
For now, I am only trying to reorder the control/presentation level.

You are currently inserting the item container into the source collection that contains the data items.
The following example shows how to implement drag&drop within a DataGrid (the same DatagRid).
If you implement the MVVM design pattern, you would move the actual item move operation to the view model, where the type of the items is known which would enable to perform semantic checks whether the drop position is allowed or not or if a type conversion is required (in particular when you move data between different controls). You generally want to avoid that a control knows the explicit data type it handles (other than object).
MainWindow.xaml
<DataGrid AllowDrop="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}"
          PreviewMouseMove="DataGrid_PreviewMouseMove"
          PreviewDrop="DataGrid_PreviewDrop"
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
          PreviewDragOver="DataGrid_DragOver" />

MainWindow.xaml.cs
private bool isDragDropActive;

private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.LeftButton is MouseButtonState.Released || this.isDragDropActive)
  {
    return;
  }

  this.isDragDropActive = true;

  var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
  object dragedRowItem = dataGrid.SelectedItem;
  int draggedItemIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
  var dragDropInfo = new DragItemInfo(draggedItemIndex, dragedRowItem, dataGrid);
  _ = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dataGrid, dragDropInfo, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void DataGrid_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DragItemInfo)))
  {
    return;
  }

  if (e.OriginalSource is not DataGridRow dataGridRow)
  {
    if (e.OriginalSource is not DependencyObject dependecyObject 
      || !dependecyObject.TryFindVisualParentElement(out dataGridRow))
    {
      return;
    }
  }

  var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
  var dragDropInfo = (DragItemInfo)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragItemInfo));

  // Don't allow to drag&drop between different DataGrids
  if (dragDropInfo.Source != dataGrid)
  {
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;

    return;
  }

  object dropTargetRowItem = dataGridRow.Item;
  int dropTargetRowIndex = dataGridRow.GetIndex();
  if (dropTargetRowIndex == dragDropInfo.ItemIndex)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (dataGrid.Items.SourceCollection is IList sourceCollection)
  {
    sourceCollection.RemoveAt(dragDropInfo.ItemIndex);
    sourceCollection.Insert(dropTargetRowIndex - 1, dragDropInfo.Item);
  }
}

private void DataGrid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DragItemInfo)))
  {
    e.Handled = true;
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    return;
  }

  var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
  var dragDropInfo = (DragItemInfo)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragItemInfo));
  if (dragDropInfo.Source != dataGrid)
  {
    e.Handled = true;
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
  }
}

private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  this.isDragDropActive = false;
}

DragItemInfo.cs
To move items between different ItemControl instances  that do not use the same source collection, you would have to store a reference to the source collection of the drag source in the below DragItemInfo structure to allow you to remove the dropped item from the original source.
internal readonly struct DragItemInfo
{
  public DragItemInfo(int startIndex, object item, ItemsControl source)
  {
    this.ItemIndex = startIndex;
    this.Item = item;
    this.Source = source;
  }

  public int ItemIndex { get; }
  public object Item { get; }
  public ItemsControl Source { get; }
}


Thanks for the response. It will just not work on my coding structure. I have got it resolved.

Sorry, I don't understand you, I guess. Why isn't this working?
